# Incomplete keys without a KeyFactory?

Tags: .net, .net-core, google-cloud-datastore

Google's samples [show a way to create a key](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-dotnet/blob/master/aspnet/2-structured-data/Models/DatastoreBookStore.cs#L29) without the need for a KeyFactory. Is there an analogous way to create an incomplete key without the KeyFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to create an incomplete key without a key factory:

```
new Key().WithElement(new Key.Types.PathElement { Kind = "your entity kind" });
```